# Validate async multiple fields redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to validate the username and email with my express-app, but on the asyncValidate method, when i validate one, the other error state disappear.

```
const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch, props, field) => {
    if (field === 'username') {
        const url = config.dev_api_url + `/validation/username/${values.username}`
        return axios.get(url).then(res => {
            if (res.data.username === true) {
                throw { username: 'Already exists' }
            }
        })
    } else if (field === 'email') {
        const url = config.dev_api_url + `/validation/email/${values.email}`
        return axios.get(url).then(res => {
            if (res.data.email === true) {
                throw { email: 'Already exists' }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the function where i render the input error.

```
renderInput = form => {
    let fieldClasses = 'field fluid'
    let inputClasses = 'ui fluid input '
    let messageType = ''
    let messageContent = ''
    let iconType = ''
    if (form.meta.error && form.meta.touched) {
        messageType = 'error'
        messageContent = form.meta.error
        fieldClasses += ' error'
        inputClasses += ' icon'
        iconType = 'error'
        if (form.meta.error === 'password_error') {
            messageContent = (
                <em>
                    <b>1 Uppercase</b> letter <br />
                    <b>1 Lowercase</b> letter <br />
                    <b>1 Number</b> <br />
                    At least <b>8 characters</b> long <br />
                </em>
            )
        }
    } else if (form.meta.touched) {
        inputClasses += ' icon'
        iconType = 'success'
    }
    return (
        <div className={fieldClasses}>
            <label>{form.label}</label>
            <div className={inputClasses}>
                <input {...form.input} autoComplete="off" type={form.type} placeholder={form.placeholder} />
                {this.renderIcon(iconType)}
            </div>
            {this.renderMessage(messageType, messageContent)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

When i throw a new error, the other one disappears. here are some images.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: First link of your image gives me access denied. Can you please send the accessible link so I can edit your post again?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11K_QHG_c_YhweyrNiZ-cFdvyUP35Kefj

Comment: Thats a folder with the three images

Comment: Please show your component code where you have set your error hide/show code

Comment: Yeah sure, wait a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is gonna be brief.

Is a mess to do that with Redux-Form, so i better use Formik, is lighter, and just handle the necessary things, unless you need some features of redux-form, this is the way to go.

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview

Comment: You can pass a function to every field so you can validate it (it accepts promises).

Answer (score 2):

I have found a not too dirty way to do it - in case anyone needs to use redux-form:

```js
const asyncValidate = ( values, dispatch, props, field ) => {
    let validationPromises = [
        {
            field: "field1",
            request: axios.get(`validationUrl1/${values.field1}`),
            error: "Error message 1"
        },
        {
            field: "field2",
            request: axios.get(`validationUrl2${values.field2}`),
            error: "Error message 2"
        }
    ]

    let promisesResolved = validationPromises.map(promise => promise.request.catch(error => ({ error })));

    return axios.all(promisesResolved).then(
        (args) => {
            let errors = {};
            args.forEach( (r, idx ) => {
                if(!r.error){
                    errors[validationPromises[idx].field] = validationPromises[idx].error
                }
            })
            if(Object.keys(obj).length > 0){
               throw errors
            }
        }
    )
  }
```